# Adding IDs to models in another library C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a library that has a model that needs to be serialized in two different ways in two different projects.

They basically look like

```
public class Computer
{
    public string DnsHostname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OperatingSystem { get; set; }
    public string ServicePack { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<LocalGroup> LocalGroups { get; set; }
    public List<LocalUser> LocalUsers { get; set; }
}
```

In one project, I need to serialize as XML.  In another projected I'm persisting through the EF.  EF wants an ID, though, and that's where I've had a bit of trouble.

Also, another gotcha in this scenario is that the EF project has to be able to deserialize the objects and persist them to the database.

So I really thought what I wanted was interfaces so I developed interfaces like `IComputer`, `ILocalGroup`, and `ILocalUser`.  The problem is that if I change `List<LocalUser>` to `List<ILocalUser>` the class that implements the interface will not be satisfied unless the type of the implementer is `List<ILocalUser>` though I really want it to be `List<LocalUser>` because EF won't use the class that implements the interface which has the Id.

Hopefully I was clear enough.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to include Id in the Interface rather than just the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

For the Id serialisation issue, is there any possibility of marking some of the properties as Key's (with Data Annotation) to help Entity Framework Serialize the class? Ie.

```
public class Computer
{
  public string DnsHostname { get; set; }
  [Key]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string OperatingSystem { get; set; }
  public string ServicePack { get; set; }

  public List<LocalGroup> LocalGroups { get; set; }
  public List<LocalUser> LocalUsers { get; set; }
}
```

As for the interface issue, this article may help / provide you with some extra thoughts on the subject: [Faking interface mappings with EF](http://www.daedtech.com/faking-an-interface-mapping-in-entity-framework/)